# How to use additional parameters when committing using git-gui?

Tags: git, git-gui

Currently we have a problem with our pre-commit hooks so we skip it using the "-n" parameter when committing from the command line. How to use this or any other additional parameters when committing using git-gui?

Comment: @tomwaitforitmy No [`-n`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--n) parameter for commit?

Comment: Ups. Somehow I didn't search long enough ...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the GUI itself, nothing in the doc, I'am afraid this is **not an option you can use within git-gui**, you'll have to stick to the CLI for this.